# Organizative by categories efficiently

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to save a list of **500k** of entities, all of these entities have a *category* and *ranking* in these category. I think about and see some ways to save this, but really I want know the more efficient, tricks, ideas, tips...

I want start this of the better possible way :)

The main use is show the rankings ordered by categories and these ranking **can change daily**.

**Way 1**

```
Entities
-----------
id | name | categoryId | ranking |

Categories
------------
id | name
```

**Way 2**

```
Entities
------------
id | name

Categories
------------
id | name

Rankings
------------
id | entityId | categoryId
```

On the final phase of the database creation, It will be a properly optimisation

Comment: how about calculating them on the fly ? Or run a `create event` event once an hour or daily, like the stack does.

Comment: Will you be asking for "Show an ordered list of categories for a particular Entity"?  Or for "all Entities"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For illustrative purposes only. Mysql Create Event manual page [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html).

show variables where variable_name='event_scheduler';

```
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| event_scheduler | OFF   |
+-----------------+-------+
```

ooops, the event scheduler is not turned on.

Well I can wait all day long, events aren't even turned on

`SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`  -- turn her on

show variables where variable_name='event_scheduler';

```
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| event_scheduler | ON    |
+-----------------+-------+

create table trips
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    status int not null,
    created_at date not null
);
insert trips(status,created_at) values (0,'2014-09-09');
```

Create the Event:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `set_trips_finished`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2015-08-23 00:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN

  UPDATE trips
  SET status = status+1
  WHERE date(created_at) < curdate();

END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

-- list all events by schema name
show events from so_gibberish;

or

show events\G; -- <--------- I like this one from mysql> prompt
show events; -- <--------- from workbench / sqlyog

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Db: so_gibberish
                Name: set_trips_finished
             Definer: GuySmiley@localhost
           Time zone: SYSTEM
                Type: RECURRING
          Execute at: NULL
      Interval value: 1
      Interval field: MINUTE
              Starts: 2015-08-23 00:00:00
                Ends: NULL
              Status: ENABLED
          Originator: 1
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8_general_ci
```

select * from trips;

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id | status | created_at |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |      0 | 2014-09-09 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

wait a few minutes (note my event runs every minute)

select * from trips;

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id | status | created_at |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |      3 | 2014-09-09 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Event has run 3 times. Ok, looks good.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = OFF;

-- turn her off if so desired
```